# iOS ViewDidLoad/WillLoad etc NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have a fairly complicated question and if anyone could answer that i will be very grateful. So basically i have a tableView which goes to another view if you select a row. and this detailView will access a web server and retrieve data. My problem is when the server is not found.

When the server cannot be accessed due to poor internet connection or because the server is an internal server etc it shows an alert message. But when i click 'OK' on the alert message and then in the tableview i select another row the alert message does not appear. Nor does it even go into the second class (in my case jsonviewcontroller).

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
NSLog(@"DID SELECT");
Item *selectedItem = (Item *)[self.fetchedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString * urlString = [CONST_FEED_DISCRIPTION_URL stringByAppendingString:selectedItem.guid];
NSDate * dateString = selectedItem.date;
JsonViewController *jsonViewController = [[JsonViewController alloc] initWithURLString:urlString date:dateString];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:nil
                                                              action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:CONST_NAVIGATIONBAR_COLOR];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jsonViewController animated:YES];
[backButton release];
[jsonViewController release];
}
```

When you click on another row it does go into this method and changes the color of the navigation bar etc as written in the code but doesnt exactly go into jsonviewcontroller. Although the first time around it does. I am thinking its probably because the View of jSonviewcontroller never loaded because i am accessing the service from viewwillappear and since the view never appears it doesnt go into viewdidload. I dont know what i am missing here.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://x"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
_rssFeedDetailViewConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    while(!finished) {
      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
  }
```

}

The delegate methods for NSURLConnection are implemented as well -

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
      [responseData appendData:data];
      _json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([error code] == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
        // if we can identify the error, we can present a more precise message to the user.
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSLocalizedString(@"No Connection Error", @"Error message displayed when not connected to the Internet.") forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
         NSError *noConnectionError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet userInfo:userInfo];
         [self handleError:noConnectionError];
} else {
     // otherwise handle the error generically
     [self handleError:error];
  }
     finished = FALSE;
     [responseData release];
     [connection release];
   // Show error message
 }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
      finished = TRUE;
      [responseData release];
      [connection release];
 }
```

It will be really great if someone could help me out with this. Thank you. My question again is - WHY IS MY JSONVIEWCONTROLLER NOT Loading from the didselectrow method the second time.

Comment: When you do funky non-standard things then bizarre results occur. First you should not push the view controller in your tableview delegate, but dispatch that to the main queue to do when the runloop runs again. Secondly, why are you doing this loop in while(!finished) in viewWillAppear. You are blocking other messages the system is trying to send you. Do what experienced iOS people do, which is throw up a spinner or HUD so the user knows something is going on. If the jsonViewController is never even going to show the user a result, then use NSOperations and put a spinner over your table.